# Python: Compute confidence intervals for a non-linear fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, confidence-interval, uncertainty

I have some x data and y data --> Just as an example

```
x_data = [5, 6, 6.2, 6.3, 6.7]
y_data = [5.2, 6.8, 8.2, , 8.9]
```

and now I want to fit a non linear function

```
def func(x, a):
     return 0.2* a**2 * x**2
```

with scipy. 
For that I use

```
prams, params_cov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x_data, y_data)
```

But I also have error bars for the x and y data. So I don't want to fit just a line
but an error band with fillbetween.

```
x_err = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]
y_err = [0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.03]
```

But for that I need the confidence intervals regarding the error bars.
Does someone know how to compute them? Or how to fit the function regarding the error bars
and getting an error for the fit from that?

Best regards

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. First `scipy.optimize.curvefit` accepts a `sigma` which can be used for your `y_err`. I would prefer using Monte Carlo simulation of your data and getting a mean and an SD for the fit using your errors. The latter can then be multiplied by 1.96 (95% confidence) and divided by `sqrt(4)` for your 4 data points.

Comment: Okay, thanks and how do I perform such a MC simulation?

Answer (score 0):

Using Monte Carlo like estimation of the fit parameters to take into account your errors would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def myfunc(x, a):
     return 0.2* a**2 * x**2

x_data = np.array([5, 6.2, 6.3, 6.7])
y_data = np.array([5.2, 6.8, 8.2, 8.9])
x_err = np.array([0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5])
y_err = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.03])

trials = 1000
my_guess = (2)

fit_params = np.zeros((1,trials))

for i in range(trials):
    x_sim = x_data + np.random.normal(scale=x_err)
    y_sim = y_data + np.random.normal(scale=y_err)

    params, params_cov = curve_fit(myfunc, x_sim, y_sim, my_guess)

    fit_params[0,i] = params

mu = np.mean(fit_params)
ci = np.std(fit_params) * 1.96 / np.sqrt(np.size(x_data))
print ("Mean a = {:.3f} +/- {:.3f} (95% CI)".format(mu, ci))
```

Yielding: `Mean a = 0.987 +/- 0.031 (95% CI)`

Note: This assumes that your errors are distributed according to a normal distribution.

More commonly, one uses a t-test taking into account the degrees of freedom and the variance for your fitted parameter, which can be calculated as follows:

```
dof = np.size(x_data) - 1 # degrees of freedom:
# calculate student-t value
a = 0.05 #(1-0.95, 95% CI)
tval = t.ppf(1.0-a/2, dof)

params, params_cov = curve_fit(myfunc, x_data, y_data, 1)

ci = tval*np.sqrt(params_cov)[0]
print ("Mean a = {:.3f} +/- {:.3f} (95% CI)".format(params.item(), ci.item()))
```

Yielding: `Mean a = 0.990 +/- 0.056 (95% CI)`